# About the Dell Nautilus Firmware Update Utility; I cannot find UsbMake.exe file

Tags: hard-drive

I am a new Server install user trying to wrench on a Dell R710. Box from eBay came with 2016 Server Evaluation Edition. Trying to learn AD, PowerShell, VMWare etc. So I bought extra memory, and 6 Hitachi drives (600MBs at 10k) to fill out the box because it only had 2 dell harddrives (300Mbs at 10K) with the buy. I can see the 6 HSBT drives in the BIOS but they won't RAID. Now I'm updating the the firmware but I don't see the UsbMake.exe file as per instructions on the Dell website. Dell says : "Once you have downloaded and extracted the file, you should run the UsbMake.exe file, located in the folder you extracted the files to". When I looked for this .exe file I cannot find it!! I must be missing something....I downloaded the latest ver that I saw on the site....Dell Nautilus Firmware Update Utility dated Oct/2018. And saw no/searched no find this UsbMake.exe file to run the boot file. I must be doing something wrong....can someone point out my error?? Thanks
Stan**

Answer (score -1):

I went to youtube and found an answer. The Dell site lists this file as UsbMake.exe but the file others ran was dddp.exe otherwise known as the diagnostic distribution package. I don't know when it was re-named or what is going on. But Dell should straighten it out. It took me two days to get on the right track. It sucks.